# Eclipse: How to deploy ear project into separate managed server in Weblogic (non AdminConsole)

Tags: eclipse, oracle, deployment, weblogic, bea

I'm using Eclipse for J2EE project development. Target app server is Weblogic10R3. 
I was successfully deployed my ear project to weblogic via Run As.. Eclipse feature.
By default it deploys to AdminConsole server. Because of project specific issues I have to deploy into separate managed server (not Admin Console).

Am I able to override deploy behavior? I didn't find required settings inside server plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying to a managed server is supported as long as you have configured the server connection as remote vs local. You can do this even if your "remote" server is localhost. If you aren't sure, you probably need to create a new instance in the Servers View. The local vs. remote option is set in the new server wizard.

Once you have a remote server defined, double-click on the instance in the Servers View and you will see an editor open with various options, including those related to publishing.